# Ports 80 and 88 still open after closing them on windows server 2019

Tags: windows, windows-firewall

I have closed ports 80 and 88 on Widows Server 2019 using the firewall (inbound rule), but the ports are still listening. Why those ports are still open and listening after I closed them with firewall?

Thank you in advanced,

Answer (score 1):

It's open because you have a service that open them.. IIS ?.. The firewall does not close them, it block them to be used depending on yout rule you set there